# SONARQUBE preferences page not getting displayed in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

I have installed SONARQUBE from Eclipse marketplace and restarted the eclipse as well.
But I am getting the below error while selecting SonarQube from Preferences page.

`An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui (351)`. And when I tracked through the root exception is below. Please help.

Root exception:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:299)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
```

Answer (score 0):

After I installed, "  m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional)" from the Luna update site, the preferences page worked.